# Url как сделать

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть ссылка вида:
site.com/?id=1

А нужно, чтобы url становился site.com/novosibirsk

В зависимости от id, должен меняться сам url
Пример:
site.com/?id=1 -> site.com/novosibirsk
site.com/?id=2 -> site.com/krasnodar

В какую сторону вообще гуглить, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: `В какую сторону вообще гуглить, подскажите, пожалуйста`     .htaccess rewrite rule

Comment: А можно как-то изменять url, но чтобы страница не переходила на измененный url?

Comment: Не могу сказать, я правила переадресаций только под nginx писал

Comment: @pubbersk как понять, поменять URL, но чтобы страница не переходила на измененный ? Сами себе противоречите. RewriteRules себе опишите. Это делается `одной строчкой` для Вашей темы.